# Will this electric guitar wiring scheme be noisy?

Tags: noise, troubleshooting, transducer, floating

I want to wire my guitar using two SPDT switches for my pickup selector.  This is so I can have four sounds: lower, upper, both in parallel, both in series.  I'm concerned that when it's set to use just the lower pickup (as shown in the schematic) that it will cause some noise/hum to be added to the output signal since the upper pickup still has one wire connected to the output jack with the other wire left floating.  If this does add noise, will it help much if I keep the wires from the upper pickup very short (an inch or so)?

[image: guitar wiring set to use only the lower pickup]

Comment: Are you actually using DPDT switches?  As drawn you show two SPDT types.  If using two DPDT types perhaps you could have a wiring scheme that prevents problems.   A 2 or 3 ganged rotary switch would likely provide a better selection method.

Comment: Ouch! that was such a sloppy mistake!  I meant to say SPDT, the schematic is what I had in mind.  Thanks for the heads up!  A ganged rotary would be like a 3P6T or like I had this old parallel port printer selector which had a 25P2T.  I haven't tried any  of those yet, but I do have what looks like a 6P6T rotary from an old turntable/radio/8-track/cassette player.  It has 3 layers, each with 14 terminals and 5 detents (so 6 positions).  I might try that if this doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fine.

The inductive pickup of noise from the pickup that is connected with only one wire will be entirely prevented. Its extremely large series resistance (of the open switch) prevents any signal contribution.

It will pickup a slight bit of electric field noise as will any dangling conductor that is connected to your circuit, such as the bridge, the strings, even yourself. But this noise is *common-mode* noise. As opposed to a differential signal between the two poles of your guitar cable, the common-mode noise is usually not amplified, so it doesn't matter either.

Another intuitive way, you can see why this will be fine is the following: With a standard pickup selector, the unselected pickup is still connected with one side to the "ground" node of the guitar circuit, but doesn't contribute noise. Since the guitar output is a differentiel voltage between its two output poles, anything dangling on the "ground" pole is no better or worse than dangling on the "signal" pole.

Comment: That seems to agree with what I've seen from a quick search of guitar pickup wiring options.  Here is a web page with two similar switching options: https://www.1728.org/guitar10.htm

Comment: @Nedd I have some circuits in some of my guitars where an open-ended pickup ends up dangling on either the inner pole or on the ring pole of the connector. Neither causes any anomalous noise.

Comment: @tobalt  Excellent!  I was starting to think I would have to disconnect the upper pickup by adding a third switch (pole?) for the "lower only" situation.  Thanks so much for your answer.